# How do I stop these self-referrals and get accurate referrals from our cross-domain eCommerce data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Basically, I work for a theater and we send patrons to our primary website (we'll call this theater.org) to look at events and choose what tickets to buy and when they go to purchase tickets, we have put links in our primary webpages to our ticketing platform (we'll call this tickets.com).

Now, I have set up cross-domain tracking so that I can see people once they get onto tickets.com and see if they purchase a ticket. Great! But I can't really see where those people are specifically coming from because the referral source is always theater.org. I would like to see the original referral to theater.org that led to the purchase on tickets.com.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've added the allowLinker (true) and the cookieDomain (auto) to my cross-domain Google TagManager
- I have added both domains to the Referral Inclusion List (now I just get "direct" as the source for my eCommerce transactions instead of theater.org )

Additional info:

- I have used the Analytics debugger console to see that the user-id changes as I move from one of my domains to the other, so that's definitely the primary issue
- I see correct referrals on my Page Views for the theater.org , but not tickets.com

Comment: make sure  you have enabled `allowLinker` and both domains listed within linker settings on tickets.com

Comment: The referal exclusion list is meant for payment gateways where you come to domain A, go temporarily to domain B, and then return to domain A. In that case the original attribution is kept and domain B is ignored on domain A. Domain B never knows anything about the proper attribution. In your case you basically stop at domain B, and tell it to ignore the referral (i.e. the only attribution source it ever knows about), so all traffic is direct. As @Xtothel has pointed out, the proper solution is cross domain tracking, which carries over the attribution from domain A to domain B.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure both tickets.com and theater.org both use the same Google Analytics property ID (UA-XXXXXXX-X) and have cross-domain tracking configured in the GTM container for BOTH domains.

Then you can look at the acquisition report tp get a sense of how people are arriving at your site OR dimensions like "previous page" or segment your goals by sessions that have visited a specific page.

Comment: It appears as if they are both using the correct property ID (per the GA Debugger). I have only one GTM container with that is the theater.org domain, and within that I have the Cross-Domain Tracking tag with both urls under Auto Link Domains. Is that correct do you think?